# Android Studio Linter Suppress warnings on class but not members

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-studio, lint

I have been playing around with the new Linter in `Android Studio 2.2 preview` and I have encountered an issue with suppressing warnings at a class level.

**Example**

```
public class HomeTabletFragment extends HomeFragment
```

This generates a linter warning on the `public` access modifier, since this `fragment` is not referenced outside of this `package` it can be made `packageLocal`. The `fragment` cannot be made `packageLocal` for the following reason.

From the Fragment documentation:

`Every fragment must have an empty constructor, so it can be instantiated when restoring its activity's state. It is strongly recommended that subclasses do not have other constructors with parameters, since these constructors will not be called when the fragment is re-instantiated; instead, arguments can be supplied by the caller with setArguments(Bundle) and later retrieved by the Fragment with getArguments().`

Now this is problem with the linter.

However when I make add

```
@SuppressWarnings("WeakerAccess")
public class HomeTabletFragment extends HomeFragment
```

To the class all `WeakerAccess` warnings get removed from the class.

Is there a way to suppress `WeakerAccess` warnings on the class and not all members contained in the class?